# How do I clear all Firebug JS breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, firebug, breakpoints

I seem to have a strange Firefox/Firebug issue where Firebug is suspending JS due to invisible/corrupt breakpoints. (Firefox 3.6.17, Firebug 1.7.2) This may or may not be related to jQuery (version unknown).

Since Firebug keeps a persistent list of set breakpoints, is there a way to clear out everything firebug might be remembering? I tried to reinstall Firebug, but that did not seem to help.

I have tried searching for the issue but of course a search for "firebug breakpoints" returns thousands of tutorials on how to use firebug breakpoints.

Comment: As of Firefox Quantum 68.01 it seems as an option to clear all breakpoints is still not easy to find and obviously most of the answers below are outdated for this environment.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Under the [Firefox profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Navigating_to_the_profile_folder), find the `firebug` folder.
2. Make sure that Firefox is closed.
3. Edit or delete `breakpoints.json` as desired.

Comment: This is the only correct answer as firebug will sometimes continue to break on a line of code after you've removed all breakpoints.

Comment: Cleaning up this file made a very noticeable difference in page load times when debugging using Firebug. There were far more breakpoints than I expected to see in my JSON file that should have been removed long ago, but were lingering.

Answer (score 35):

Open the web site where you want to clear the breakpoints, Open Firebug or press F12.
from the right panel, you should see Watch, Stack and Breakpoints,
Click on breakpoints dropdown and click on [image]

Comment: This only clears out 1 page's breakpoints.  The OP seemed to be asking to clear ALL breakpoints -- which is a good idea, as Firebug's files retain junk long after it is needed/relevant.

Comment: Yes it is for only selected website as mentioned in my answer, Adams response is the solution for this question.

Comment: Even though it clears all the breakpoints, but the firebug still continues to break at different points. However, this worked for me:  
- Add a breakpoint on a line where it is stopped if there was no breakpoint for that line.  
- On 'Breakpoints' dropdown menu, select 'Disable all breakpoints'

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the Library/Mozilla folder on Mac. Its because its hidden. To unhide Open terminal and run this

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

You should be able to find it folder now

To unhide run this

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
```

**I recon an easy way:** In firebug toolbar click the bug icon and follow ***reset all firebug options***:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Right side tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this if it still breaks

- Insert about:support in Firefox url bar
- find folder 'firebug'
- delete file breakpoints.json
- restart Firefox

*restart what ever editor you are using in conjunction e.g Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar situation on newer Debugger Tools versions.

In my case, the files remained opened without any breakpoints on them. If I closed the tabs of these files, they would reopen automatically upon reloading the page.

After reloading, the debugger would still show no breakpoints on these files, or even the option to remove/disable breakpoints, as mentioned in **@AjayR**'s answer.

---

**SOLUTION**:

The solution I found was manually going to each opened file tab and placing a breakpoint on any line. After that, going to the "*Breakpoints*" section of the debugger and clicking the "*Remove all breakpoints*".

I am leaving this solution as I have searched a bunch but no other source on the web provides this solution.

[image: Remove breakpoints action]