# Why is Firebug hitting non-existent break points?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've been using Firebug to debug some javascript I have on one of my pages.  Recently it has started hitting non-existent "break points" at seemingly random spots in my javascript.  It seems like most of these points are in third party libraries like jQuery, but it also stops on custom javascript.

I'm not seeing any errors at these lines and I definitely don't have break points there.  Can anyone think of why Firebug would be stopping here?  It's getting to the point where I have to hit the "Continue" button about 20 times to get the page to finish Javascript execution...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I've been experiencing the exact same thing - so you're not alone.  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259604/how-do-i-clear-all-firebug-js-breakpoints, but this is not the same problem, as I already checked that.

Comment: Are you auto-pausing on anything other than breakpoints, like exceptions?

Comment: Have you tried to reinitialize all Firebug options ?

Comment: Do you see any breakpoints in the breakpoints tab? (right pane-> Watch | Stack | Breakpoints)

Comment: @SKS - Yes I had 4 break points there, but none that were anywhere near where it was stopping.  Just to be safe I deleted them all and it's still happening.

Comment: @davin, hmmm I'm not sure, how would I check?  I have been checking to see if I get any exceptions and I'm not seeing any though.

Comment: @Golmote, no I haven't.  How would I do that?

Comment: By clicking on the left Firebug menu, you should see an "Options" submenu and a "Reinitialize all options" action. (Not sure about the translations in english =° )

Comment: Looks like you have activated some "Break on..." feature (Break on Error, Break on XHR request...). Check all your Firebug tabs and make sure the Pause button is active in none of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem and fixed it like so:

1. Uninstall firebug in the firefox add-ons manager
2. Close firefox
3. rm -rf [profile_folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Navigating_to_the_profile_folder)/firebug
4. Delete all firebug-related lines from profile_folder/prefs.js
5. Reinstall firebug

Hope this helps!

---

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with firefox, this is happening because you might have enabled auto breakpoints. Check here http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel for more details about what i am talking about. Disable them on console and script panel and everything will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but it is also the top result for searches: like firebug random breakpoints.

In my experience, assuming this is not due to break on exception or other settings, every time this happens to me there is some collision with jQuery, or another library. Sometimes even name spacing does not keep you safe, and this is very hard to debug.

Most recently I had a function named: name_space1.nestedns.focusCursor(). Something was messing with my focusCursor function.. didn’t figure out what, just changed the name.

Farther in the past I had a function or var named ns.companyabreviationToolTip... and there was collision and breaking on this as well. Changed ToolTip to something obscure, and everything was happy. Maybe firebug has a secret break on collision setting. If this is a bug, I hope it does not get fixed… it seems useful.

Comment: @scrtForm,danAnds: While this may not answer the question in your situation, it perhaps answers it for others. Collision is a viable cause of the OP's problem, and while his question is the first result for searches, it makes sense to have alternative answers. If there is some specific problem with the formatting of my answer, point it out. Critique is always good. But the copy paste comments you left really do not provide much insight into the problem. I clearly do not have a different question, need clarification from the author, or the need to comment below the OP's question. Thanks