# FireBug 1.7.3 still breaks on removed breakpoint

Tags: firefox, firebug, breakpoints

There's a bug in FireBug: I accidentally clicked where the line numbers are, which sets a breakpoint.  So I clicked again to remove it.  Now it's breaking there every single time.  And I've tried setting/removing a breakpoint, but it doesn't work.  I've even tried clicking the pause icon, which I see suggested elsewhere, but it does nothing -- it doesn't even change.  I've even tried setting it to be a conditional breakpoint that is always false so it should never fire.  No cigar.  I even tried uninstalling FireBug and reinstalling it!

(Please note that I am using FireBug 1.7.3 with FireFox 3.6.25, and have to for a reason, and cannot upgrade.)

[I'd post an image, but I cannot until I have 10 rep pts!]

How can I remove all breakpoints?
Do I have to uninstall / reinstall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear all Firebug JS breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259604/how-do-i-clear-all-firebug-js-breakpoints)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

In Firefox, go to URL `about:support`

Check the Profile Directory

Open containing folder

Go into folder `firebug`

Delete `breakpoints.json`

Comment: Dawood, you are the man! It worked great! Thanks!! =) I can't vote you up until I have 15 rep pts, sorry! :(

Comment: You can "accept" the answer, though, by clicking on the green 'tick'.

Comment: Same symptom showed up in firebug 2.0.1 firefox 30.0; same basic solution still applies. It didn't work the first time so I added some steps: disable firebug, exit firefox, delete the file, restart and reenable. (Maybe only one of those extra steps was really necessary, but I don't know which.) The weird part is I looked in the file and it contained only one entry, referring to a completely different site.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with Firefox 79.0. Since the breakpoints.json does not exist anymore in this version (how does firebug keep track of its breakpoints now?), I tried

- In Firefox, go to URL `about:support`
- Click "Refresh Firefox"

This resets everything to default (language etc.) but also removed "ghost breakpoints".

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to fix this for newer Firefox versions, that, as was mentioned above, don't have the breakpoints.json anymore.

- Open the Profile folder
- Navigate to the `storage\permanent` folder
- Close Firefox
- Delete the `indexeddb+++fx-devtools` folder

The deleted folder will be generated again, so don't worry.

You'll probably lose some configuration on the devtools, but it's better than refreshing your entire browser.