# Disable the debugger statement through the browser

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, javascript-debugger, debuggervisualizer

I am trying to style a piece of code that has the `debugger` keyword in it.
I am using the debugging window(IE, FF, Opera) to see CSS style effects but the debugger is stopping every time I refresh the page(as it should).

Can I toggle or disable the debugger keyword through the browser(not by deleting it from my code) so I could do the style I want without it bothering me every time I refresh the page?

```
myApp.service('User', ['$localStorage', function ($localStorage) {
    debugger;
    this.$storage = $localStorage;
}]);
```

Thanks

[The debugger statement](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-debugger-statement)

Comment: I have no idea why you'd use the debugger statement instead of opening the developer tools and the debugger with `F-12` at need.

Comment: this link may be useful      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259604/how-do-i-clear-all-firebug-js-breakpoints

Comment: @ManirajSS Thanks. I will check this with firefox but it is also not the most straight forward solution. Also I need solutions for Opera and IE if any known.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sometimes I have some piece of code that I would like to come back later and reinspect it, In order to follow the flow or to see events and for that I like to keep the debugger keyword in the code, until I push to the sourcecontrol.

Comment: To disable all breakpoints and debuggers see [disable all breakpoints and debuggers in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767986/7487135)

Answer (score 22):

You can now select "Never pause here" from the menu after right-clicking on a line number. It will prevent Chrome from pausing on the `debugger` statement.

[image: Never pause here]

Answer (score 0):

f10 => for pass step by step line

### f8  => for pass to another debugger

you can see all styles in chrome performance tab without handling javascript issues

chrome>>  inspect(f12) > performance > reload

[image: Inspect(f12)>performance]

Answer (score -1):

You should delete the debugger when it's not being used.  It should only be used in the lines of code you are currently testing.... There's no reason to have it in your code when you're not testing the code directly before or after the debugger.

Comment: Even though is an general answer for "deleting", the OP searches an answer that does not includes deleting  `debugger;` from the code (question specifies "disabling").