# How to prevent chrome pausing on debugger lines?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I added some third party js code to my project and problem is when I try to debug my js files, chrome pauses on third party js code. Is there any way to disable debugger lines?

```
data.info= getInfo();
debugger; //like this lines
process(data.info);
```

Comment: So the third party library has the `debugger;` lines in it?

Comment: @George Yes it has hundreds of debugger; lines

Comment: Well that seems horrible. Look at the upvoted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569955/disable-the-debugger-statement-through-the-browser). It may provide a temporary solution. What's the third party library just out of curiosity?

Comment: If you have script locally can't you find and replace ?

Comment: [Balckbox JavaScript Source Files](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing)

Comment: @Andreas blackboxing is not working because when I refresh page debugger lines starts working again.