# how to totally ignore 'debugger' statement in chrome?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, google-chrome-devtools

'never pause here' can not work

[image: before]

after I continue：

[image: after]

still paused

Comment: Looks like "never pause here" works only for the first statement on a line. Consider submitting a bug report on https://crbug.com and attach a test html with the embedded script shown in your pictures.

Comment: it's because your script is anonymous: called like VM<number>. There is only one current solution: if it's possible please add //# sourceURL comment to this anonymous script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I created a ticket in Chrome 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1219519

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To totally ignore all breakpoints in Chrome, you must do as follows:

1. Open your page in the Chrome browser.
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or right-click on the page and select *Inspect*.
3. In the Source panel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to deactivate all breakpoints. (or: At the top-right corner, select *deactivate breakpoints*.)

All breakpoints and `debugger` statements will be deactivated.

I tested it in Chrome 79<sup>.0.3945.88 (64-bit)</sup> and I found that the `debugger` statement is ignored.

[image: Screenshot showing the effect of deactivated breakpoints on debugger statements]

Comment: @hellouworld. I tested it now and the debugger disabled in chrome 79. please take a look at the snapshot that I put at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @hellouworld. Maybe you aren't in the source tab or your chrome version is so old.

Comment: @Anatoliy Oblauhov. It works in Chrome 79. please take a look at the snapshot that I put at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @ImanBahrampour, could you, please, record a gif in which you add a line of any js code, then the `debugger` keyword, then again any js line of code after. And add a manual breakpoints for the two lines of js before and after the `debugger`. And record that during the execution the pause happens on the tow js code lines, but not on the `debugger` keyword. Until then I am downvoting the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ImanBahrampour, you can use a js like this 
var stop = 0; 
debugger; 
stop = 0;

Comment: This simply does not work.  To skip debugger statements, you need to click the button next to it, "pause on exceptions"

Comment: @JohnLord, The "pause on exceptions" is for exceptions and not breakpoints. for example, when an exception in throw occurs, the javascript built-in exception handler fixes it and does not pause on it but if you activate the "pause on exceptions" then you can trace your code.

Comment: they want to know how to skip debugger statements, not breakpoints.  Debugger statements trigger an exception.  You must turn off pause on exception to skip them.  That is just how it is.

Comment: When refreshing the page, the setting goes back to normal, therefore making debugger invoked again. Then, you can detect if it was invoked (based on timing) and redirect the user to prevent using the DevTools...

Answer (score 4):

To stop hitting debugger statements, you must either set a "never pause here" breakpoint, OR you must pause stopping on exceptions.
This works because debugger breakpoints are considered exceptions by the browser.

[image]