# Disable debugger statement in Chrome but keep other breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to disable *only* the `debugger;` statement in Chrome, while leaving other breakpoints intact? I'm making changes to a solution where there are a bunch of other ISV scripts I can't touch, and these are littered with them. However I'm only interested in breaking on my own code (where I set breakpoints in Chrome and don't use the `debugger;` statement).

> Let me make it absolutely clear that I **ONLY** want to disable the `debugger;` statement specifically, but leave all other breakpoints untouched. All other answers I've seen on Stack Overflow explain how to disable *all* breakpoints. This is **NOT** what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to totally ignore 'debugger' statement in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767855/how-to-totally-ignore-debugger-statement-in-chrome)

Comment: No, it's not. Please read the question again, including the added emphasis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569955/disable-the-debugger-statement-through-the-browser

Comment: Closer, thanks! It still requires me to manually set "Never pause here" for every `debugger;` statement in each script, but at least it's better to do once than to spam F8 every time.