# How to prevent chrome devtools from stopping on `debugger` keyword?

Tags: google-chrome, devtools, javascript-debugger

Is there a way to prevent chrome from stopping on `debugger` statements while the devtools window is open, and at the same time allow stopping on manually set breakpoints?

The deactivate breakpoints button (⌘/ctrl + F8) disables *both* the `debugger` statements and the user breakpoints so it's not really a solution. It would be good to somehow be able to control separately 'code' breakpoints and 'devtools' breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Never Pause Here" feature. but you need to do it for every line.

Answer (score 0):

How about two scripts to launch your app , where one script can comment out all the debugger statements and then launch the app ?

If it's that important to you right now.

Comment: That would be an answer to a different question. But let's assume that you are loading an external library that you cannot modify.

Comment: well no one puts debugger; in production builds

Comment: I only said *let's assume*, didn't say it's a production build.

Comment: See if this helps.  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569955/disable-the-debugger-statement-through-the-browser)

Comment: Thanks, yes, it lists among others the answer provided by @m.hassaballah.